# Unable to left Join in Google Big query in Tableau

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

I get this error when I perform a left join of 2 tables in Google Big Query in Tableau. But if I use custom SQL I can overcome the error but it slows down the DB.

**Error** :

> The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query. Name
>   [Column name]not found inside [Table] at [1:64]

Any help would be really appreciated . Thanks!

Comment: This might be because the column names for the join are parsed differently in Tableau and BigQuery. They making sure the columns are named in ways that work in both systems. And post the actual names so we can check.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/google-bigquery-service-was-unable-to-compile-the-query-unrecognized-name) article:

> "Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long."

If the above is not the case, can you let us know what the field name is?

The second suggestion in that article might be a good troubleshooting step as well - especially if you are using an older version of Tableau.

Comment: Any luck on this? If you figured it out on your own please add an answer and apply green check mark.